# What are all the different interfaces and their names that can be added to iptables?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, security, iptables

In iptables there are interfaces mentioned after -i , what are all the different interfaces and what are all the different names?. e.g.: [-i lo == loopback]

Can you tell me where I can find details on these naming conventions? My search always leads me to [Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) one way or another.

Comment: `ip link` or even `ip addr`

Comment: This only gives me interfaces in my machine, how can I get a comphrehensive list of interfaces.

Comment: There's no such thing (what do you mean by comprehensive anyway?).

Comment: eg: lo means loopback interface , eth0 / eth1 means ethernet interface , wlan means wireless lan interface , what are all the other types, is there a naming convention?

Comment: There is, but interfaces are not strictly bound to it. (Userspace can rename interfaces; there are at least two separate naming conventions for physical interfaces alongside the standard kernel convention. A sysadmin can make their own.)

Comment: Can you tell me where I can find details on these two naming conventions? My search always leads me here https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/ one way or another.